# How hciattach works in Bluetooth

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth

i want to know about how `hciattach` is works.

Can any body tell me the flow of this function and hows its extacly works?

Comment: Did you read the source code for it?  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: i want to know where hciattach source is in Linux?

Comment: @CarlNorum Please Can u suggest me from where i can refer this hci toll source . i want to know about what actually hciattach command do in source code

Comment: @CarlNorum Please Help..

Answer (score 1):

Here's hciattach source code from web
http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/bluetooth/bluez/tools/hciattach.c

Comment: Why don't you include relevant part of that code here? Your answer will be useless if that site goes down.